# How do I plot confidence intervals grouped per category in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have date in the following shape:

[image: Example data]

How do I plot this using python (pandas/matplotlib, or any library actually) so that it looks likes this:
[image: Example output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd have a go at doing it with a normal boxplot. Depending on how pretty you want it to be, you can get something approaching what you want. I generally use seaborn, but it's based on matplotlib, so shouldn't take much change to keep it pure mpl if you want.

I've imitated your dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [['A','A','B','B','C','C'],
       [1, 1.1, 0.7, 1.2, 0.8, 1.1],
       [1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.6, 1.4],
       [1.8, 1.8, 2.1, 2.2, 2.4, 1.7]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns = ["Group","Lower","Average","Upper"]
```

Then, I've melted the columns back into rows, and removed the average. That leaves the maximum and minimum. I've had to add in a new column as the hue, so that the items in each group are plotted separately.

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Group"],value_vars=["Lower","Average","Upper"])
df = df[df["variable"] != "Average"]
df["hue"] = df.groupby(["Group","variable"]).cumcount()
```

If you plot a box and whisker with the whis setting to 100, then it gives you the maximum and minimum, with the mean in the middle (since it's only two data points, it's the same as your column with the mean).

```
g = sns.boxplot(x='Group',
                y='value',
                hue="hue",
                data=df,
                whis=(0,100),
                meanline=True,
                showbox=False,
                width=0.5)
g.get_legend().remove()
```

I can't find a way to force the remaining part of the vertical line to be displayed. The gap is where the box goes, but you can hide it, especially since now it is meaningless. Anyway, this is the end result:

[image]

Comment: I added this before plotting: `df = df.append(df)`. Then plotted with `showbox=True` and it gives a result that fits my needs. Thanks for giving me a solid starting point!

Answer (score 0):

For case when you've already established upper and lower bounds of CI matplotlib is a lot easier to use because it can give you more tools to operate with.

The way I am doing it is by using **fill_between** with alpha 0.1. It is a method that draws an area between two lines. Here's a bit of code to get an idea of how it should work:

[Example of plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mj7K.png)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

x = list(range(0, len(df.first_org.unique()))) # matplotlib needs x values to be numerical so you'll need to encode your cat. 
                                               # values if they're in text format
y = df[df['ci_value_type'] == 'mean']['event_occurrence_frequency'].values

ucb = df[df['ci_value_type'] == 'mean-high']['event_occurrence_frequency'].values
lcb = df[df['ci_value_type'] == 'mean-low']['event_occurrence_frequency'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_figheight(15)
fig.set_figwidth(17) 

ax.plot(x,y, marker='o')

# basically, CI magic happens here
# this line of code tells matplotlib to fill a sector between certain lines on plot
ax.fill_between(x, (y - lcb), (y + ucb), color = 'b', alpha = .1) 
      
sns.set_style() # you don't have to add this if you don't want to download seaborn
                # added it here so we'll have similar looking plots

ax.set_title('Event occurence with regards to organization mentioned')
ax.grid('on')

plt.xticks(x, list(df.first_org.unique())) # little trick to get textual X labels instead of numerical
plt.xlabel('companies')
plt.ylabel('event frequency')

label_X = ax.xaxis.get_label()
label_Y = ax.yaxis.get_label()

label_X.set_style('italic')
label_X.set_size(12)
label_Y.set_style('italic')
label_Y.set_size(12)

plt.show()
```

Gist link: https://gist.github.com/theDestI/7bddf368e7e20829cf8f59bccadc073f#file-matplotlib_ci-py

I wrote a post about ploting confidence intervals on medium, so take a look at that as well if you need more info:

https://destiq.medium.com/trickycases-2-ci-plot-with-seaborn-and-matplotlib-11cd74a3fc5d